# getting result for startActivityForResult() in normal class

Tags: java, android, sd-card, filechooser

I am working on saving PDF from internet. The class I am using, to download pdf is a normal class "FileChooser.java", not an activity class. Now, I want to open a Activity to browse through the SDCard and return the selected folder path to the "FileChooser" class

I have planned to use the following code

```
private void getFolder() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT); 
    intent.setType("*/*"); 
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);

    try {
        startActivityForResult(
                Intent.createChooser(intent, "Please select the folder"),0);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

but i want the result to be in "FileChooser" (Normal Java)class

What should i do, to get the result in "FileChooser" class?

Please guide me.

Comment: btw, have You control other the Activity to browse through the SDcard? Have You tried to send intent from the activity and have BroadcastReceiver in FileChooser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the data using setresult() and get the result by using onactivity result().

The tutorial [here](http://saigeethamn.blogspot.in/2009/08/android-developer-tutorial-for_31.html) helps you.